# Barclay (EPDQ) backoffice URL

Tags: payment

It seems that there are two URLs available for barclaycard implementation.
Which one should I use?

Any other articles on the differences between these two?

- https://mdepayments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/prod/backoffice/
- https://payments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/prod/backoffice/

I received email that mentioned
  *"Problem with online post-sale http request"*

Answer (score 0):

There are two addresses, one is for the test environment and one is for the production environment.

Test - https://mdepayments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/test/backoffice
Production - https://payments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/prod/backoffice

Answer (score 0):

To solve

> ** Merchant email from EPDQ:
>   **************************************** Process Error :
>   ****************************************
>
> Problem with online post-sale http request
>   **************************************** Post-sale request result :
>   **************************************** **

You have to modify your "Mod_Security" module in your server. ( Speak to your host and whitelist the domain).

For details :
http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/395840-barclays-epdq-cpi-new-backend-problems-solved/